# Java doesn't display accent words correctly

Tags: java, joptionpane, non-ascii-characters

I have a java program that saves a text file and then outputs it contents in a dialog.
When I run the program **inside** my IDE (BlueJ) the display is as follows:
[image: program inside BlueJ][image]

As you can see in the dialog the line "1º) Mónica" appears correctly.
But when I run the same program **outside** the IDE the "Mónica" doesn't appear right, as you can see in the picture:
[image: program outside BlueJ]

How can I fix this to always display the right output?

this is the code that reads the text file to a string

```
public String recordesString()
    {
        Premios premios = new Premios();
        File recordes = new File("recordes.txt");
        if(!recordes.exists()) {
            if(!client.isConnected())
                openFTPSession();
            downloadRecordes(); // this downloads the recordes.txt file
        }
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(recordes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String string = "";
        String linha = null;
        for(int i = 1; s.hasNext(); i++) {
            linha = s.nextLine();
            String palavra[] = linha.split(" ",2);
            string += i+"º) "+palavra[1] +"  "+ premios.getPremio(Integer.parseInt(palavra[0]))+"\n";
        }
        s.close();
        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(ficRecordes));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return string;
    }
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386381/utf-8-encoding-in-jlabel-on-windows , maybe it will help you.

Comment: Could be ANSI encoding.

Comment: The second screenshot, from outside the IDE, is what you get when a UTF-8 encoded string gets interpreted as ISO-latin 1. We'd have to see a bit more of your code to tell for sure what's going on, but certain java methods use the default encoding. Perhaps this is different between the IDE and outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanner reads the file using the underlying platform's default charset.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

I'd expect the file is encoded in UTF-8 and when you run outside the IDE, the default charset is ISO-latin-1 or so. If you specify the file's encoding when creating the scanner, the results will be predictable.

```
s = new Scanner(recordes, "UTF-8");
```